# Tmux shows double the amount of space in front of command prompt

Tags: command-line, zsh, tmux

tmux n00b here, when I run tmux it shows almost the double the amount of space in front of the command prompt as compared to a regular zsh session.

[image: tmux screen]

[image: regular zsh]

I read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11237462/1081936) from SO and added the following to ~/.zshrc:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

And tried to start tmux with `tmux -u`, but to no avail.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Did you also modify `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf` and `~/.zprofile` as suggested in the answer you link to? And did you start a new terminal after adding those lines to `~/.zshrc`?

Comment: @terdon: thanks for taking a look. New terminal was what I missed. I kept opening new tmux sessions in other guake tabs without re-loading the terminal. If you can add this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~/.zshrc` file is only read once, when a new shell is started. Any changes you make there won't affect your current shell session unless you either source it manually (`. ~/.zshrc`) or start a new shell session.

So, the simplest solution is to just open a new terminal after adding those lines to your `~/.zshrc` and run `tmux` from the new terminal.